# Extending templates from a subfolder using Laravel 5 blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So in my views folder, I have a file `admin/layouts/base.blade.php`. I try to do `@extends('admin.layouts.base')` in a view (`admin/home.blade.php`) and get this error: **ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php [...]: View [admin.layouts.home] not found. (View: [...]\resources\views\admin\home.blade.php)**.

I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's not allowed in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Find controller or another class where you're using `admin.layouts.home` view name and change it to `admin.home`. This will solve the problem.

You got the error, because Laravel in trying to load `admin.layouts.home` view which doesn't exist.

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation. Can you please give an example?

Comment: Alexey tries to tell you that, somewhere in your views/ controller you are using `admin.layouts.home` that doesnt exists because path to `home` blade is `admin.home` without `layouts`

Comment: Okay. I get it. My bad!